# Connecting multiple Camel Routes in REST DSL

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to connect multiple camel routes under a single Rest controller. Currently the routes I've defined outside the Rest controlled are not being called and I'm not sure why.

**Example:**

Rest controller:

```
@Component
public class RestController extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        String listenAddress = "0.0.0.0";
        int listenPort = 8081;

        restConfiguration()
                .component("netty4-http")
                .scheme("http")
                .host(listenAddress)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
                .port(listenPort);

        rest("/")
                .post()
                .produces("application/json")
                .to("direct:route1");
```

Route1:

```
@Component
public class Route1 extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        from("direct:route1")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .log("Boo!")
```

I would expect the above to log `Boo!`, indicating it has passed through `Route1`.

I've tried using the `content enricher` EIP which also doesn't appear to work. My only guess is that the camel context needs to be injected into the `Route1` class.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Interestingly, if you define the `Route1` within the same class it works just fine...

Comment: You override the `configure()` method of the parent class without calling `super.configure()` hence the `restConfiguration()` may never be executed to start with (which you also do not extend your `Route1` from `RestController`, which you can. Next, it is benefitial to define the `rest("/")...` stuff within the actual route class itself rather than the parent class. You may define a base context path via `.contextPath(...)` on the `restConfiguration` itself if children should reuse it

Comment: Thanks this is helpful! Do you mind providing an example give the above scenario? :)

Comment: I've put up a demo-application using Camel's RestDSL on [Github](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security) which you might take a look at. In particular the [BaseAPIRouteBuilder](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/routes/api/BaseAPIRouteBuilder.java) and an extending [sample route](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/routes/api/SampleFileRoute.java)

Comment: Roman isn't using Spring Boot @Component annotations in his linked example so that's why he is combining an abstract class with a stub method (defineRoute) and inheritance to only have to have one restconfiguration in the end. 
But as https://stackoverflow.com/a/62332822/5446400 says "By using Spring Boot and annotating your REST route classes with @ Component, you'll be able to separate the REST configuration from the REST service(s) but all of them will be part of the same Camel context."
The example of the original poster should have worked.

Comment: I just tried it out: The example provided by OP is working 1:1 as intended.
Console logs of startup shows both routes are started:
Started route1 (rest://post:/)
Started route2 (direct://route1)

=> then Firing a POST request to that endpoint shows success in the console: "2024-02-28T23:26:08.696+01:00  INFO 60940 --- [tp1263972401-30] Route1:16                                : Boo!"