# Best way to define restConfiguration() with multiple rest dsl route builders in Apache Camel

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I am relatively new to camel and I'm looking for a good way to define multiple route builders using the REST DSL component in camel while using one restConfiguration() definition as this should remain the same across all route builders.

I found this question ([Connecting multiple Camel Routes in REST DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573864/connecting-multiple-camel-routes-in-rest-dsl)) in which someone linked to a base class defining restConfiguration() which will be automatically called by child classes (https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/routes/api/BaseAPIRouteBuilder.java) which is desirable as we only want to define the restConfiguration if there is a rest consumer route defined,  but this would mean the restConfiguration is called multiple times (for each child); is this the best solution?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

By using Spring Boot and annotating your REST route classes with `@Component`, you'll be able to separate the REST configuration from the REST service(s) but all of them will be part of the same Camel context.

```java
@Component
class MyRestConfig extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration()
            .contextPath("/my-api")
            .apiContextPath("/doc")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
            ...
        ;
    }
}

@Component
class BooksService extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        rest("/books").description("Books-related service")

        .get()
            .description("Lists Books according to the search parameters.")
            .produces("application/json")
            .route()
                .routeId("api-books-search")
                .to("direct://books-service-core")
            .end()
        .endRest();
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of creating a separate route for the restConfiguration you could initialize and configure a [RestComponent](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-rest/3.3.0/org/apache/camel/component/rest/RestComponent.html) directly on Camel initialization (i.e. within the `CamelContextConfiguration.beforeApplicationStart()` routine) and add it to its registry.

Comment: Thanks for your help Fabio and Roman. I will look into using beforeApplicationStart() to define my restConfiguration across all routes!